# Correct procedure for Inference from the Lasso

Tags: econometrics, lasso, machine-learning

Firstly, I'm from the more ML-y side of town so apologies for the naive questions. I have a situation with a treatment variable $D\in \{0,1\}$, covariates $X\in \mathbb{R}^p$ and a response variable $Y\in \mathbb{R}$. The treatment has been completely randomized, that is $Y(1),Y(0)\perp D$ in potential outcomes notation. I'm interested in estimating the heterogeneous treatment effect using a linear model, i.e.
$$Y_i = \alpha + \beta D_i+\delta D_i\cdot X + \epsilon_i$$
and I care about $\mathbb{E}[Y(1) - Y(0)|X]= \delta X$. I'd ideally like inference on the coefficients $\delta$ as well.

In general $p \gg n$, where $n$ is the sample size, so I plan to use the Lasso. Now in normal ML land, I would split into a train and test set. I then standardize my training set, i.e. ensure that $X$ is centered and each feature has unit standard deviation. Then I run CV to pick the best lambda on the train set, retrain my model on the full training set and then evaluate on the test set, and of course this would do a good job of learning $\mathbb{E}[Y|D,X]$. However, I'm interested in learning the best practice using LASSO to learn the HTE and provide inference in the econometrics world. For this example, that means inference on the coefficients $\delta$.

I've been diving a bit into [1] which assumes the linear treatment effects model. There they do a "double selection" procedure where they LASSO $Y$ onto $T,X$ separately, and then fit OLS on the full model onto the resulting variables with non-zero coefficients in each individual LASSO. This procedure seems to be generalized by other orthogonal ML methodologies. However in my case, since my data comes from an RCT, and I have a stronger condition than conditional independence, it seems like like the wrong approach - by definition $D$ is independent of $X$.

This leaves me with four ideas for what to do.

a) The most naive thing to do is just run the LASSO with CV on my full dataset. In general the LASSO will lead to biased estimates but does a good job at model selection. So as a final step, I can then perform OLS on the full dataset and report confidence intervals.

b) As a second alternative, I can also use a parametric bootstrap where for $B$ bootstrap iterations I fit my full data using OLS to learn $\hat{\alpha}, \hat{\beta}, \hat{\delta}$, use this model to predict noisy outcomes $\tilde{Y}_i = \hat{\alpha}+\hat{\beta}D_i+\hat{\delta}D_i\cdot X_i +N(0,\sigma^2)$ on my existing dataset $(D_i, X_i)_{i=1}^n$ and then fit the LASSO. This gives a bootstrapped distribution on the coefficients from which I can obtain CI's - note that I am still potentially reporting biased estimates on the coefficients.

c) I can use an "honest" approach ([2]) where I split my sample in two pieces, perform LASSO (using CV) on the first half, then fit OLS after the variable selection on the second half. This has the nice property of giving me de-biased estimates and confidence intervals with the right coverage if the model selection procedure is right.

**So my question to the community** - What would you do? What's best practice? Are there methods that I have missed? Thank you!!

**Bonus Question** - What is the "right" procedure for getting heterogeneous treatment effects out of a general ML model in this setting (i.e. imagine I threw everything at a neural network) and appropriate inferences?

[1] Belloni, Alexandre, Victor Chernozhukov, and Christian Hansen. "Inference on treatment effects after selection among high-dimensional controls." The Review of Economic Studies 81.2 (2014): 608-650.

[2] Athey, Susan, and Guido Imbens. "Recursive partitioning for heterogeneous causal effects." Proceedings of the National Academy of Sciences 113.27 (2016): 7353-7360